# Flutter Firebase how to add map within array

Tags: firebase, flutter

I got list.

```
final services= [
  HizmetModel(title: 'ServiceA', price: 30),
  HizmetModel(title: 'ServiceB', price: 30),
  HizmetModel(title: 'ServiceD', price: 30),
];
```

I would like to write and read this list to Firebase like below.

[image]

Comment: still not solved.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that HizmetModel has a method `toMap()` that converts `HizmetModel(title: 'ServiceA', price: 30) => {'ServiceA': 30}`.

```
List<Map> firebaseData = services.map((e) => e.toMap());
```

You can upload this List to firebase as usual.

https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview/